# How Do I Limit the Number of Simultaneous Connections to a Network Share?

Tags: windows, network-share, connection, file-sharing

Is there some mechanism to actively refuse connections to a network share in a Windows domain environment by using some predefined conditions on the server that hosts the share (if possible)?

Let's say that I would like to allow a maximum number of 10 simultaneous users connections to a network share.

Is it possible to enforce such a policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can set the maximum number of simultaneous users who can connect to the Share. You can do this in the properties of the Share. Have a read here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753521.aspx

Not that these settings exist in every version/edition of Windows that I'm aware of (since you didn't specify it in your question).